# How to calculate total using Javascript/ TypeScript reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sum, reduce

I have the following array:

```
[Title1: 111, Title2: 222, Title3: 333]
```

This array is generated from a Web Socket Service and I want to accumulate the values using reduce.

I have the following code, but I can't get it to work:

```
this.liveDataPriceTotal = this.liveDataPrice.reduce( ( previousValue, currentValue ) => Number( previousValue ) + Number( currentValue ), 0 );
```

Where replacing this.liveDataPrice with [111, 222, 333] works as expected.

Any ideas how to get the accumulated total from my array?

**Solution:**

Since I was confused and mixed up arrays and objects, I came with the following solution which accumulates the values from my object:

```
this.liveDataVolume24hTotal = Object.entries( this.liveDataVolume24h ).reduce( function( total, [key, value] ) {
    return ( value ? Number( total ) + Number( value ) : total );
}, 0 );
```

Comment: Do you have an *array*, or an *object*?

Comment: It is initialized as: liveDataPrice: number[] = []; and the values are added as: this.liveDataPrice[data['MARKET']] = data['PRICE'];

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Variable this.liveDataPrice is an object.

Comment: [Title1: 111, Title2: 222, Title3: 333] is an array of objects

Answer (score 1):

Simple exemple:

```
total: number = 0;
arrayNumb: [10, 20, 30];

this.total = this.arrayNumb.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
console.log('TOTAL = ', this.total);
```

console: **TOTAL = 60**